# How to separate a single json array into x and y values?

Tags: arrays, json, chart.js

I am utilizing Json.SerializeObject(variable) to obtain an array that I am graphing using Chart.js.
In order to get the array, I am creating a list and adding the key and its corresponding value to the list inside a foreach loop in a function that's inside of my Model in MVC that looks like this:

```
var CountryList = new List<int>();
foreach (var country in CountryData.ToList().GroupBy(...))
{
   foreach(var countryNum in country.GroupBy(...)
   {
        CountryList.Add(countryNum.key);
        CountryList.Add(countryNum...);
   }
}
return Json.SerializeObject(CountryList);
```

I was able to get the array and it looks like this:

```
[0,34,1,56,2,93,0,33,1,88,2,56,1,68]
```

The 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1 are my x values which are the keys that I added inside my loop so they should appear on the X-axis while 34, 56, 93, 33, 88, 56, 68 are my y values.
I also need to separate them into 3 different graphs like so:
[0,34, 1,56, 2,93] & [0,33, 1,88, 2,56] & [0,0, 1,68, 2,0]. How can I separate that single array so I can graph it accordingly? I am using bar graph of chart.js.

Note: If you are wondering why I am doing it this way, I need to create multiple graphs and I don't want to have a function for each graph. It will lead me to have over 20 functions that way. If there is another way that you recommend, please let me know.

The values that I am getting are from a database.

This is my expected output:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZspJ.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnJwG.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdxgu.png)

Comment: Could you show input data and expected output data. I currently dont understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MarkoTaht I just made changes to my post to add the links in. The data I am getting is from a database. The foreach loop is in my Models folder of my MVC and I am trying to graph it in my views folder.

Comment: But whatabout the input data? What is the format, what it means, what do the graphs mean. This is important info to understand the underlying problem. The numbers and keys right now are too abstract to get anything meaningful out of them. Like 1 soulution would be to have a list of lists. And when you itrerate over data you keep track of the previous X value. Now if previous X = null or previousX < currentX you create new list in the list of lists and start cumulating data in the new list. And where nessesary you fill in the missing places with 0-es. But you need to know amount of X-es

Comment: Its just... it seems to me that the basic approach you have is a bit off. 

Why cant you return a json {graph1: {labels: [0,1,2], values: [34, 56, 93]}, graph2: {labels: [0,1,2], values: [33, 88, 56]}, graph3: {labels: [0,1,2], values: [0,68,0]}. Cause looking at graph.js api, it seems to me that data in this format would be alot more easier to use.

Comment: Sorry that I am not being clear with my question. I am going to look into how I can save my data into 3 different json parameters like you are saying. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

If i can assume that the attributes 0,1,2 are connected to a single Country. So that each graph = 1 country. Im also assuming you are using C# because the code seems to use Linq.

```
Dictionary<string, Graph> dict = new Dictionary<string, Graph>();
foreach (var country in CountryData.ToList().GroupBy(...))
{
  Graph g = new Graph();
  foreach(var countryNum in country.GroupBy(...)
  {
      g.addEntry(countryNum.key,countryNum...);
  } 
  dict.add("someName", g); // add different name for different graphs to avoid overriding values
}
return Json.SerializeObject(dict);
```

And the Graph class itself

```
class Graph {
   List<int> labels = new List<int>();
   List<int> values = new List<int>();

   public void addEntry(int label, int value){
       labels.Add(label);
       labels.Add(value);
   }
}
```

If my assumptions are correct then this should do the trick. If my assumptions are wrong, then i hope this can atleas help you move in the right direction.

Added bonus is, you can modify the Graph class to make it more generic for the graph.js. Like add in color info etc. So that on the JS part you just have a method makeGraph that takes this JSON as input and then based on values inside constructs a graph for you.

Comment: Thanks, all of your assumptions are correct. However, when I look on the dev console, my values are coming in as {KeyName1: {...}, KeyName2:{...}, KeyName3{...}}. The ellipsis are actually shown and I can't seem to find the entry that I added even when I expand it. How can I access each entry?

Comment: Json.SerializeObject returns a JSON string. So. Again me and my assumptions :D. If the Graph.js part is purely JS. Then you could just do `const obj = JSON.parse(...);`  Now you can `obj.KeyName1` or `obj["KeyName1"]`. Or a more generic way ``for(const key in obj){console.log(`${key}: ${obj[key]}`);}`` There are more ways to iterate objects in JS. But i think this should help you move forward.